Check if Cell Contains Month and Compare to Date
I have a dataset that contains a log of tests passed and failed. The tests are in YYYY MONTHNAME format. Look at the screenshot below as an example

I have specific dates for these tests on another tab named Test Date Mappings that I need to compare to columns A and B.
View sample sheet
What I am trying to achieve is columns F and G. On column F, if a person has a test in column C that falls between the start (column B) and end date (column C) then they have a "Yes" in column E. Same with column G using the tests failed column (E).
If a person does not have a start date then the cell should be left blank.
Edit: Updating image and post to reflect a scenario I did not think of initially.


Here's one approach you may test out:
=map(C2:index(C:C,match(,0/(C:C<>""))),lambda(Σ,if(or(map(iferror(split(Σ,", ",)),lambda(Λ,
 index(isbetween(xlookup(Λ,--'Test Date Mappings'!A:A,'Test Date Mappings'!B:B,),indirect("A"&row(Σ)),indirect("B"&row(Σ))))))),"Yes","No")))



the formula as of now checks if atleast one pass test is within the given
start/end dates


My apologies. I failed to provide one scenario. I will update my question and the test sheet. I have some people who have not started the program so they will not have a start or end date. I need them to just be blank instead of Yes or No. I'm sorry for not thinking of this sooner. The great news is this looks like it's working well as is.

Updated the post and the sheet.

I think I solved for it. I added a IF(INDIRECT("U"&ROW(Σ))="","", THERESTOFTHEFORMULA) right after that first lambda(Σ, and it seems to work. Do you agree this is the best method? If so can you update your answer so I can choose it?

Selecting this answer. With the tweak I mentioned above I'm confident it gets me to my desired result. Thanks for your help.
